# Create multiple databases based upon the same model in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Little background, the company I work for is starting to create software for drilling sites. With that said, my boss would like to have a database created for each new project that is started. Each database name would be named after the project, but the schema would be the exact same for all of them. He would also like to, at any point in time, to switch and access previously created databases. Is something like this possible with entity framework? I've created my model, and my initial database. But I'm not sure how to go about creating a new database, or accessing an old one.

Comment: does the schema the same, or different for every db?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: Edited to answer you question.

Comment: just use a different connection string.

Comment: Id db schema is exactly the same, than use different connection string, what is the problem?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, the question is how? There's only one connection string inside the app.config. I would need to have this string generated and saved every time I create a new database.

Comment: could you have different app.config file for every project?